# Show differentiability of $f(x)=\lVert x\rVert^7 \cos(\lVert x\rVert^{-49})$ at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Is the function $f: \mathbb{R}^{m} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, given by $$f(x) = \cases{\lVert x\rVert^7 \cos\left(\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^{49}}\right) &,  $x\neq$ 0 \\ 0 &, $x=0$}$$ differentiable at $0$ ? Justify.

What I usually do is

1. Check if the function is continuous. Yes ? Go to step 2. No ? The function is not differentiable.
2. Check if $L(x) = Df(0) = \partial_h f(0)$ is linear. Yes ? Go to step 3. No ? Not differentiable in $0$.
3. Use the squeeze theorem to show that $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(0) - L(x)}{\lVert x\rVert} = 0$$ *(note: $a=0$)*

However I'm lost with this function and I don't really know how to perform the calculations with this function.

For example, I don't know how to squeeze this function to show that it is continuous. Neither how to calculate $\partial_h f(0)$ with these crazy norms.

Comment: $|\cos(\varphi)| \le 1$ helps for squeezing ...

Comment: Oh sure ! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{\lVert x\rVert}=\lVert x\rVert^6\cos\left(\frac1{\lVert x\rVert^{49}}\right)$$and that therefore$$0\leqslant\frac{\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(0)\bigr\rvert}{\lVert x\rVert}\leqslant\lVert x\rVert^6.$$So, $f'(0)$ is the null function.